# ColorBox maximum size

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

How can I limit the maximum size of ColorBox?

```
jQuery(document).bind('cbox_open', function(){
    jQuery.colorbox.maxWidth = '90%';
    jQuery.colorbox.maxHeight = '90%';
});
```

This code is not working.(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Scalephotos

If true, and if maxWidth, maxHeight, innerWidth, innerHeight, width, or height have been defined, Colorbox will scale photos to fit within the those values.

```
$("a.gallery").colorbox({rel: 'gal', scalephotos:true title: function(){
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">Open In New Window</a>';
}});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but colorbox called automaticially from Joomla component. Can I use this code in this situation?

Comment: Yes you can use this code... you have to import colorbox plugin in your code